# Yandex Maps Api Как вычислить zoom карты по расстоянию?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Карта находится в квадратном div 50% 50%
Я вычисляю радиус круга по такой схеме:
1) Определяю центр карты и верхнюю точку над ней.
2) Беру расстояние между этими точками.
данное расстояние зависит от зума.
Вот код:

```
public calculateRadius() {
    // находим центр карты и координаты её углов
    const bounds = this.myMap.data.getBounds();
    const center = this.myMap.data.getCenter();
    // получаем точку лежащую справа по центру
    const rightPoint = [center[0], bounds[1][1]];
    const radius = this.myMap.yaMap.data.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(
      center,
      rightPoint
    );
    console.log("currRadius", radius);
    const _position = _.cloneDeep(this.position);
    _position.radius = radius;
    this.positionChange.emit(_position);
  }
```

Теперь мне нужно сделать обратное преобразование.
Я получаю расстояние, как мы выставить соотсветвующий ей зум?

Comment: а Вы знаете что круг на карте это не круг на земном шаре? точнее пропорции сохраняются только на экваторе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, я понимаю. То есть вы хотите сказать что это невозможно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используqте setBounds() - это метод класса Map, в него передавайте координаты двух ваших точек, для которых вы вычисляли расстояние.
Обратите внимание в методе на опцию preciseZoom - по умолчанию он отключен, поэтому метод подбирает такой целый масштаб, чтобы координаты в него поместились, при этом могут появиться отступы с краёв карты. Если опцию включить, то масштаб будет подобран такой, чтобы координаты "прилипли" к краям карты.

Comment: Скажите, а возможно управлять отступами? То есть мне нужно сделать так чтобы радиус или координаты правой точки круга, помещались в круг нарисованный через CSS. Вот что я в итоге хочу сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032136/yandex-maps-cделать-определение-расстояния-как-на-картинке