# Yandex Maps cделать определение расстояния как на картинке

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Коллеги, как cделать определение расстояния как на картинке
Исходные данные:
1) использовать web
2) размер контейнера с карты - произвольный, зависит от расширения.
3) круг всегда должен быть в центре карты.
4) радиус круга равен текущей ширине контейнера с картой

Нужно:
1) Определять текущий радиус круга в метрах (зависит от зума)
2) При получении радиуса и точки выставлять такой зум карты, чтобы радиус круга = входному радиусу (рисовать круг и центровать карту по радиусу и центру окружности

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: С какой стадией у Вас проблемы?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Со всеми. Например как нарисовать данный круг - через css или API? Как сделать через API?

Comment: Через апи  - придется считать фигуру, т.к. круг на карте отличатется от круга на гобуе ну и соответственно на поверхности земли

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вы можете мне помочь с этим за оплату?